# How to prove that this equality is the development of a fourier series?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, fourier-series

how can I show that this identity is a  development of a fourier series?
$$f(x)=\sin^3 x=\frac{3}4 \sin x-\frac{1}4 \sin 3x$$

I tried this:

obtain the Fourier coefficients whih $$b_n=\frac{2}\pi \int_0^\pi{\sin^3 x\;\sin nx}\;dx\qquad n=1,2,3,\cdots$$

where $$f(x)=\sin^3 x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\sin{nx},$$ as clearly $b_n=0\;\;\forall n\not=1,3. \quad b_1=3/4\wedge b_3=-1/4$. 
But this integral is too long from the way I have tried

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the addition formulas for the sine function:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sin(3x)&=&\sin x\cos(2x)+\cos x\sin(2x) = \sin x(1-2\sin^2 x)+2\cos^2 x\sin x\\ &=& \sin x -2\sin^3 x + 2(1-\sin^2 x)\sin x = -4\sin^3+3\sin  x\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence:
$$\sin^3 x = \frac{3\sin x-\sin(3x)}{4}$$
as wanted. As an alternative:
$$\sin^3 x = \left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2}\right)^3 = \frac{e^{3ix}-e^{-3ix}-3e^{ix}+3e^{-ix}}{-8i} = \frac{3\sin x-\sin(3x)}{4}.$$
The Fourier series is unique, hence if such an identity holds, it is the Fourier series you are looking for.

Comment: yes, I can prove this, but I have not able to do the development in Fourier series :c thanks anyway.

Comment: The Fourier series is unique, hence if such an identity holds, it is the Fourier series you are looking for.

Comment: How I demonstrate this claim? I would get the Fourier coefficients to prove.

Comment: @CristianRodríguez: Write $\sin^3 x$ as $\frac{3\sin x-\sin(3x)}{4}$. Then you can use the orthogonality relations to get: $$b_1=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^3 x\sin x\,dx = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{3\sin x-\sin(3x)}{4}\,\sin x\,dx = \frac{3}{4}$$ and so on.